# How to refresh the line numbers in sed

Tags: bash, sed

How can you refresh the line numbers of a sed output inside the same sed command?

I have a sed script as follows -

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f 
/pattern/i #inserting a line
1~10i ####
```

What this does is that it inserts lines wherever the pattern is matched and then inserts `####` every ten lines. The problem is that it inserts the hashes every 10 lines according to the line numbers of the original file before inserting the lines for the matching pattern. I want to refresh the line numbers after inserting the lines and use them for inserting the 4 hashes every 10 lines.

Anyway this can be done without piping the output into a new sed?

Comment: It's (probably) not possible with `sed`

Comment: I thought there might be a way where you could configure the insert lines to change the line numbers. That way when the next time lines are inserted, new line numbers are used.

Comment: please update the question with sample input and expected output;

Comment: Don't forget that `sed`, as its name implies, operates on a _stream_ of characters, reading from an input source to an output source. Therefore, all operations are expressed by positions in the original input source. This is different from a text editor, which (at least conceptionally) modifies a file in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting challenge. If your file is not too large, the following may work for you (tested with GNU sed):

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nEf
:a; N; $!ba
{
  s/([^\n]*pattern[^\n]*\n)/#inserting a line\n\1/g
  s/\n/ \n/g
  s/\`/####\n/
  :b
  s/(.*####\n([^\n]* \n){9}[^\n]*) \n/\1\n####\n/
  tb
  s/ \n/\n/g
  p
}
```

Explanations, line by line:

- No print, extended RE mode (`-nE`).
- Loop around label `a` to concatenate the whole file in the pattern space (reason why its size matters).
- Add `#inserting a line\n` before each line containing `pattern`.
- Add a space before all endline characters.
- Insert `####\n` before the first line.
- Label `b`.
- Append `####\n' to anything followed by` ####\n` and 10 space-terminated lines, removing the final space (to prevent subsequent matches).
- Goto `b` if there was a substitution.
- Remove all spaces at the end of a line.
- print.

Note: if your file does not contain NUL characters the `-z` option of GNU sed saves a few commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -Ezf
s/([^\n]*pattern[^\n]*\n)/#inserting a line\n\1/g
s/\n/ \n/g
s/\`/####\n/
:a
s/(.*####\n([^\n]* \n){9}[^\n]*) \n/\1\n####\n/
ta
s/ \n/\n/g
```

Note: with the hold space we could probably do the same on the fly, instead of storing the whole file in the pattern space.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/.*pattern/# insert line\n&/mg
         s/([^\n]*\n){10}/&####\n/g
         s/^/####\n/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory.

Insert desired text before lines containing `pattern`.

Insert `####` every 10 lines and before the first line.

Comment: Masterpieces! This should be the accepted answer.